# Spock fails when PostConstruct calls a injected service

Tags: grails, spock

Can any one tell me how to solve the issue of PostConstruct get called before mocking:

Service:

```
class MyService {
    SecondService secondService // injected

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        myFunction()
    }

    void myFunction() {
        secondService.doSomething()
    }

}
```

Test:

```
@TestFor(MyService)
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {
   void "testing my service"() {
      given:
         MyService service = GroovySpy(MyService) {
             myFunction() >> null
         }
      then:
         true
   }
}
```

Gives following error:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method doSomething() on null object
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have @TestFor(MyService) - MyService instance will be created automatically and you can use it as 'service'. And you don't need to create MyService manually.

So you can only delete @TestFor(MyService) or use it and remove MyService service.

But you also need to correctly mock 'secondService'

```
@FreshRuntime
@TestFor(MyService)
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {

    def secondService = GroovyMock(SecondService)

    def doWithSpring = {
        secondService(InstanceFactoryBean, secondService, SecondService)
    }

    void "testing my service"() {
        when:
        service.myFunction()
        then:
        1 * secondService.doSomething()
    }
}
```